# UI glitch when writing own group box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

in my program i have a group box, i didnt like that the groupbx provided in visual studio doesnt have a border colour property so i used this code to create my own group box.

```
public class MyGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    private Color _borderColor = Color.Black;

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return this._borderColor; }
        set { this._borderColor = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the text size in groupbox
        Size tSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);

        Rectangle borderRect = e.ClipRectangle;
        borderRect.Y = (borderRect.Y + (tSize.Height / 2));
        borderRect.Height = (borderRect.Height - (tSize.Height / 2));
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRect, this._borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

        Rectangle textRect = e.ClipRectangle;
        textRect.X = (textRect.X + 6);
        textRect.Width = tSize.Width;
        textRect.Height = tSize.Height;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), textRect);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), textRect);
    }
}
```

which works "fine", i got myself a black border group box instead of grey, except when the window is moved the group box glitches out like so, [image: picture]

is there a fix for this or will i have to use the visual studio group box to prevent this issue? i am using C# winforms

Comment: I just used your groupbox and it did not do this, how do you initialize yours (don't need controls inside) so I can maybe reproduce it

Comment: Don't use `e.ClipRectangle`. Use `this.ClientRectangle` instead.

Comment: @EpicKip its just grabbed from the toolbox

Comment: @IvanStoev i changed `e.ClipRectangle` to `this.ClientRectangle` and its perfect, if you want to add it as answer id be happy to accept

Comment: @IvanStoev : Makes me wonder why? What is the difference here??

Comment: @Taw No sure what's the difference here, but in general `e.ClipRectangle` is the invalidated rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.cliprectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) is misleading - *Gets the rectangle in which to paint.*. Actually this property represents the *invalidated* rectangle of the window, which is not always the full rectangle. It can be used to skip painting of elements that are outside that rectangle, but not as base for painting.

But the base rectangle for all painting should be the [`ClientRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the control being painted. So simply replace `e.ClipRectangle` with `this.ClientRectangle`.